# How remove from first till a certain string in array

Tags: bash, string, array

How do we remove from first till a certain string in array just like that of in plain string by `${..#..}`  e.g. `${s#abc}`

```
$ s=(e u i o foo a)
$ t=(${s[@]#*foo})
$ echo "${t[@]}"

e u i o a
```

instead of expected:

```
a
```

How to correcly do it so solve such need ?

Answer (score 1):

If switching to  `zsh` is an option, you could do it as:

```
s[(r)foo,-1]=()
```

Where `r` is the *reverse [subscripting flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-subscript-flags)* which allows you to reference array members by value instead of index, here to assign the empty list `()` to the range of elements from the first with value `foo`, to the last  element  (`-1`).